# AngularJS and prevent to encoding url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, encoding, angular-ui-router

The problem is that angular encodes url as default when you use special characters like [ ] { }
I would like to know how I can prevent browser to encode url like below address:

http://www.hepsiburada.com/troy-bosch-chef/elektrikli-alet-el-aletleri-c-13003080?puan=3&filtre=[{"id":"activemerchants","values":["hepsiburada"]}]

**Update1:**

This is my router:

```
    $stateProvider.state("products", {
    url: "/:firstparams/:secondparams?filters&sort",
    params: {secondparams: {squash: true, value: null}},
    views: {
        main: {templateUrl: "/view/productList.html", controller: "ProductListController", reloadOnSearch: false},
        reloadOnSearch: false
    },
    reloadOnSearch: false,
    onEnter: ("$rootScope", "$stateParams", "EVENTS", function ($rootScope, $stateParams, EVENTS)
    {
        $rootScope.$broadcast(EVENTS.ON_STATE_CHANGED, $stateParams);
    })
});
```

});

Comment: When generating this url, can't you just use encodeURIComponent(), passing in the string value of the intended "filtre" value ?

Comment: I mentioned a link above, I think they use htaccess to rewrite url but failed in my code.

Comment: Is this from a GET request made from your app to the server? If so, you should use the `params` property of the $http request to set those, and angular will carry to encode properly

Comment: Actually I just get data from url and after validation send data to my server side (api) and return result to show on page.

Comment: Not clear at all where this url is created or what you are trying to do with it. Please provide all relevant code and information

Comment: @charlietfl for example this a angular base website:
http://rubensdev.com/todo-app/#/firstrun?filters=[{id:3}]
When you open this site in firefox url will not change but in chrome will change.

Comment: should use proper url encoding/decoding. This is well documented. Still not clear where url is generated

Comment: @charlietfl 
My router is something like above.

Comment: That doesn't explain how urls are generated or why they aren't being properly encoded/decoded. You need to put more work into explaining how all of this is used.

Comment: @charlietfl Url will not generate in code, this is a simple get method to get params.

Comment: That doesn't explain much. Until you provide full details of situation you won't be able to get much help. Server languages have URI encode/decode ability and so does javascript